# How can the anagram code be improved and made faster?

Tags: c#, anagram

The program runs slowly when there are more than 10 characters, I would like to do it quickly. I do not understand how I can improve and ask for your help.

And still need to count and number those combinations that do not occur in their original positions, I think if I add this logic, then the program will work even longer, and this also requires your advice

P.S. sorry for my English)

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(632, 430);
        button1.Visible = true;
        // Get the items.
        string[] items = txtItems.Text.Split(' ');
       // string[] items = txtItems.Text.ToString;
        // Generate the permutations.
        List<List<string>> results =
            GeneratePermutations<string>(items.ToList());
        //  results.Where(x => !HasCharacterAtSamePositionAsInOriginal(items, x));
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        // Display the results.
        lstPermutations.Items.Clear();
        foreach (List<string> combination in results.Where(x => !HasCharacterAtSamePositionAsInOriginal(items, x)))
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                lstPermutations.Items.Add(string.Join("", combination.ToArray()));
            }
            else
            {

                lstPermutations.Items.Add(string.Join(" ", combination.ToArray()));

            }

        }

        // Calculate the number of permutations.
        long  num_permutations = Factorial(items.Length);
        txtNumPermutations.Text = num_permutations.ToString();

        // Check the result.
     //  Debug.Assert(lstPermutations.Items.Count == num_permutations);

}

    private List<List<T>> GeneratePermutations<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        // Make an array to hold the
        // permutation we are building.
        T[] current_permutation = new T[items.Count];

        // Make an array to tell whether
        // an item is in the current selection.
        bool[] in_selection = new bool[items.Count];

        // Make a result list.
        List<List<T>> results = new List<List<T>>();

        // Build the combinations recursively.
        PermuteItems<T>(items, in_selection,
            current_permutation, results, 0);

        // Return the results.
        return results;
    }

    // Recursively permute the items that are
    // not yet in the current selection.
    private void PermuteItems<T>(List<T> items, bool[] in_selection,
        T[] current_permutation, List<List<T>> results, int next_position)
    {
        // See if all of the positions are filled.
        if (next_position == items.Count)
        {
            // All of the positioned are filled.
            // Save this permutation.
            results.Add(current_permutation.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            // Try options for the next position.
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!in_selection[i])
                {
                    // Add this item to the current permutation.
                    in_selection[i] = true;
                    current_permutation[next_position] = items[i];

                    // Recursively fill the remaining positions.
                    PermuteItems<T>(items, in_selection,
                        current_permutation, results, next_position + 1);

                    // Remove the item from the current permutation.
                    in_selection[i] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return n!
    private long Factorial(long n)
    {
        long result = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) result *= i;
        return result;
    }

    bool HasCharacterAtSamePositionAsInOriginal(string [] originalWord, List<string> anagram) //check the symbol occurs in its original location or not
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < originalWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (originalWord[i].Equals(anagram[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for the items array?

Comment: People on StackOverflow won't do your homework for you. As you have noticed, this is a horribly inefficient method of determining an anagram. Here is a clue: What you need to do is to use a dictionary in the form `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Each time you encounter a word, sort it into alphabetical order and check if it exists as a key in the dictionary or not. If it does not, add it and a new list and add the word to the list. If it does already exist, add the word to the list. You should be able to find all the anagrams in a list of 100k words in about half a second.

Comment: @Hyarus, input data: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
                 output: 1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6 9 8
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 8 9 6;
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 9 6 8;
1 0 3 2 5 4 8 6 9 7;
1 0 3 2 5 4 8 9 6 7;
1 0 3 2 5 4 8 9 7 6;
1 0 3 2 5 4 9 6 7 8 ;and so on, completed in 11 minutes

Comment: @StuartGrassie, can you show an example how to use? Or link where used.

Comment: @Adham, after reading your question again and looking at your sample input data I obviously realise now that you aren't talking about word anagrams, but number anagrams. I think? I still think you could use the method I describe though. I won't do your homework for you though, you'll learn more if you try to figure it out yourself :)

Comment: @StuartGrassie, and for letters and numbers works, I just gave an example with numbers to make it clear.
Thanks for the advice, but I'm not asking to do my homework  for me, just point out the right solution, what to use and how to use. Because I'm just starting and do not know such things yet.

Comment: It’s the simple problem to sort the inputs and compare if they are equal they are anagram otherwise not.